# jq: remove elements from array and output into a single line each one

Tags: jq

Is there any way to output as "slurp" format and input array?

```json
[
{ "id": "id1", "value": "value1"},
{ "id": "id2", "value": "value2"}
]
```

I'd like to get:

```
{ "id": "id1", "value": "value1"}
{ "id": "id2", "value": "value2"}
```

Each element outside of array, and each element into a single line.

I've tried with `-c` option. but it generating all array into a single line.

I mean, `-c` option is generating me:

```json
[{"id":"id1","value":"value1"},{"id":"id2","value":"value2"}]
```

Comment: `jq --compact-output '.[]'` ?

Answer (score 0):

[`jq -c '.[]'`](https://jqplay.org/s/RoG6x-xnlDq) does what you want:

In:

```json
[
 {"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"},
 {"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"},
 {"foo": 42, "bar": "less interesting data"}
]
```

Out:

```json
{"foo":42,"bar":"less interesting data"}
{"foo":42,"bar":"less interesting data"}
{"foo":42,"bar":"less interesting data"}
```